# What the process automation should I choose?

Tags: apex, approval-process

I am a beginner at Salesforce.
I have an exercise to practice my Salesforce knowledge.
The following is my exercise description in short:

The application has one object that is used to store some information. When requestor creates new record of this object, his department's manager must approve the request and a notification email will be sent to each employee or a group of employees automatically. On the other hand, the application has another object that is used to config who is the recipient, who is the approver, what is the email subject, what is the email body. It means the system must get data from this object to send request and notification email instead of set the fixed recipient and approver.

How should I do?

Thanks

Comment: here's salesforce help guide on which automation tool to choose https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=process_which_tool.htm&language=en_US

Answer (score 1):

You may want to study Workflow process for this assignment.It contains approval process,sending email etc.
Refer to [Workflow and Approval](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=customize_wf.htm&language=en_US)

Answer (score 1):

The first problem statement would need an approval process to be developed however records need to be submitted explicitly using the submit for approval  button. You would need an Apex trigger to implictly submit the record for approval. For the second problem statement you would need to uae a workflow with the necessary field update actions to set the values and send notiidcation emails in combinarion with using email templates